# Burn ISO to USB with free space left

Tags: linux, boot, usb, partitioning, iso-image

From what I tried, when you download for example Tails **usb image (.img)** and burn it to USB, it will only take space **required** for the image and will left **remaining space free** so I can format it and use it like it's a normal USB. (For example with Tails, it creates one partition about 2GB big and the rest is free space that I can use as normal storage and it still boots Tails without any problems.)

And so I wanted to move from Tails to Kodachi, but Kodachi doesn't have an USB image, only an ISO and ISOs always used the **whole** USB sticks when I burned them.

So, is it possible to burn an **ISO** to USB without using the **entire storage**, only the required space?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think that it will do harm if you just create folders alongside your operating system files as long that you make sure that the installation-files themselves are not in a folder themselves. As long as you don't overwrite existing folders or take similar names ex. (syslinux and isolinux in ubuntu installation) this should be fine.

You could also shrink the size of your iso partition and create a second one with files in it. This might make it harder to boot from the correct partition and will take more space of your usb-device.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

> So it is possible to burn an iso to usb without using entire storage, only the required space?

Since ISO9660 was originally meant for CDs it does not contain a partition table, so no OS will know what to do with the leftover space. Moreover, iso files (and devices) are always mounted read-only, so you won't be able to use that partition for other storage.

However, you have at least three options, depending on what you want to do:

1. On *NIX systems, you have Xorriso [https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/] which lets you mount the ISO filesystem as write / modify.
2. If you just want the ISO and a second partition for personal data, your best bet is to create a partition table for the USB with two partitions, format the first as FAT32/EXFAT (compatible with EFI booting), mount the ISO and copy the files to the FAT partition. You will also need to set the 'bootable' and 'ESP' flags on the first partition to tell UEFI that they contain an OS. You can format the second partition as any FS you want. Notice however that Windows in its infinite wisdom does not recognize partitioned USBs, at least until recently. In that case you will be stuck with using the first partition for both the OS and your data, or using your second partition only on *NIX systems.
3. If what you need is a multi-boot device (as in having multiple ISOs in one USB), there are a few utilities that do the trick, like Ventoy and MultiBootUSB. I They basically use method #2, with an added OS-like overlay to select and boot from different iso files or partitions in the USB.